# Spring returning a html file from a static repository (not bundled with the war file)

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

Is it possible for Spring to return a html through a Spring controller (using Viewresolver) wherein the html file is not bundled with the same project but is available at another context on the application server the project is deployed to? (Example: The html file is on an apache http server but is available to the user on the same domain as  that of the app server that needs to return this html file)

Comment: I guess this can be done provided the `ViewResolver` of the other context is returning the HTML.

Comment: @SantoshJoshi In my usecase, the other context is simply an apache http server serving static html.